# Webpack will not resolve JQuery-UI Definitions

Tags: jquery-ui, webpack

I have the following code in my TS file...

```
require("jquery-ui/ui/widgets/datepicker.js");
require("angular-ui-date/dist/date.js");
```

When I run the code I get the following error...

> Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'jquery-ui/datepicker' in //code/my-app/node_modules/angular-ui-date/dist
>    @ ./~/angular-ui-date/dist/date.js 3:66-97

So I ran `tsd install jqueryui --save` and then added the following to the same file as the require...

```
/// <reference path="../../../typings/jqueryui/jqueryui.d.ts" />
```

based on `src/main/typescripts` but I still get the same warning when running webpack

Comment: It seems like your angular-ui-date is dependent on jquery-ui/datepicker  so may just installing jquery-ui/datepicker can resolve it.

Comment: I tried that already hence `require("jquery-ui/ui/widgets/datepicker.js");`. I think the type definition needs to be wired up or something

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a issue with latest version you are using. It has nothing to do with type definition. if you open angular-ui-date/dist/date.js you will find that it is requiring

```
require("jquery-ui/datepicker")
```

which does not exist 
to workaround you could change it manually to `require("jquery-ui/ui/widgets/datepicker")` but that's a ugly solution i think.
There is also an issue on github and there is also suggestion for workaround

[Please see the isse here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-date/issues/169)

Answer (score 1):

I added an alias to the resolve object in the webpack configuration file.

```
'resolve' : {
  'alias' : {
    'jquery-ui/datepicker' : 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/datepicker'
  },
},
```